# Magento 2.2 sample data composer version fails

Tags: composer, magento2.2-dev

I'm trying to install sample data on Magento 2.2:

```
composer config http-basic.repo.magento.com public_key priv && \
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com && \
bin/magento sampledata:deploy && \
bin/magento setup:upgrade && \
rm -rf var && \
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But when "bin/magento sampledata:deploy" runs, I get an errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/module-tax-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-tax-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/module-swatches-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-swatches-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package magento/module-bundle-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-bundle-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package magento/module-review-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-review-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 7
    - The requested package magento/module-msrp-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-msrp-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 8
    - The requested package magento/module-cms-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-cms-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 9
    - The requested package magento/module-theme-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-theme-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 10
    - The requested package magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 11
    - The requested package magento/module-widget-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-widget-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 12
    - The requested package magento/module-customer-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-customer-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 13
    - The requested package magento/module-downloadable-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-downloadable-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 14
    - The requested package magento/sample-data-media 100.2.* exists as magento/sample-data-media[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 15
    - The requested package magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-wishlist-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 16
    - The requested package magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 17
    - The requested package magento/module-configurable-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-configurable-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 18
    - The requested package magento/module-product-links-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-product-links-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 19
    - The requested package magento/module-sales-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-sales-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 20
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-sample-data 100.2.* exists as magento/module-catalog-sample-data[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.0.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
There is an error during sample data deployment. Composer file will be reverted.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't use composer to install the 2.2RC sample data. You need to follow the instructions for [installing sample data by cloning the repository](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-clone.html).

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to rename auth.json.sample to auth.json from magento root and add the public and private keys to the json.

```
{
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     }
  }
 }
```

2-Try to download sample data package using composer

```
composer require magento/module-xx-xx-sample-data
```

hope this will help you to resolve the issue. worked for me!!

Happy Coding!!